# ActiveMQ Artemis, Spock, & Spring JMSMessagingTemplate - test is unstable

Tags: spring-boot, spock, spring-test, activemq-artemis, jmstemplate

I have a Spring Boot application I'm trying to migrate to use `spring-jms` dependency instead of `spring-activemq`.

I have a few tests written with Spock. I also want to use either `spring-jms-server` or `artemis-junit` module. These tests use a `JmsMessagingTemplate` to send a message on a multicast address (topic), the message is then processed by some `@JmsListeners` on the consumers queues of these topics.

It seems that the test fails sometimes because the message sent via a `JmsMessagingTemplate` fails to be acknowledged or never arrives at the listeners.

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi</groupId>
    <artifactId>audit</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <common-lib.version>1.8.0-SNAPSHOT</common-lib.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.5</jacoco.version>
        <sonar.tests>src/test/groovy,src/test-integration/groovy</sonar.tests>
        <spock.version>2.2-M3-groovy-3.0</spock.version>
        <logbook-spring-boot-starter.version>2.14.0</logbook-spring-boot-starter.version>
        <jacoco.version>0.8.5</jacoco.version>
        <sonar-maven-plugin.version>3.9.1.2184</sonar-maven-plugin.version>
        <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
        <maven-surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
        <gmavenplus-plugin.version>1.13.1</gmavenplus-plugin.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-lib</artifactId>
            <version>${common-lib.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-artemis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.zalando</groupId>
            <artifactId>logbook-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${logbook-spring-boot-starter.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>10.0.23</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.ibm.db2</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-junit</artifactId>
            <version>2.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--        &lt;!&ndash; https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.activemq/artemis-server &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--        <dependency>-->
<!--            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>-->
<!--            <artifactId>artemis-server</artifactId>-->
<!--            <version>2.21.0</version>-->
<!--        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${spock.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <enableAssertions>false</enableAssertions>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unit-tests</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Spec.java</include>
                            </includes>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*ITSpec.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-tests</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <!-- Never skip running the tests when the integration-test phase is invoked -->
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <includes>
                                <!-- Include integration tests within integration-test phase. -->
                                <include>**/*ITSpec.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${gmavenplus-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testSources>
                        <testSource>
                            <directory>src/test/groovy</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </testSource>
                        <testSource>
                            <directory>src/test-integration/groovy</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </testSource>
                    </testSources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unit-test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jacoco.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonarsource.scanner.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${sonar-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

In my specification, I use either

```java
@Rule
public EmbeddedActiveMQResource server = new EmbeddedActiveMQResource();
```

or the `artemis-server` dependency to start a server.
I also tried to use `sleep()` and `@Retry` but tests seem to hang in the `send()` method even when they are retried. In the logs, I can see that the sent message is sometimes not acknowledged. If this is the case once, `retry` hangs in the same spot.

You can also see my attempt to get a "fresh" server by using : `start()`, `setReceiveDelay()` and `stop()` on the server in the `setup()` and `cleanup()` fixtures.

**AuditMessageArtemisSpec.groovy**

```java
package be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.audit.service

import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.audit.domain.AuditMessage
import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.audit.domain.AuditMessageHistory
import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.audit.repository.AuditMessageHistoryRepository
import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.audit.repository.AuditMessageRepository
import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.common.domain.Headers
import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.common.service.JmsService
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
import org.apache.activemq.artemis.junit.EmbeddedActiveMQResource
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan
import org.springframework.test.annotation.DirtiesContext
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner
import spock.lang.Retry
import spock.lang.Specification

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("artemis")
@ComponentScan("be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi")
@Slf4j
class AuditMessageServiceArtemisSpec extends Specification{

    static final SLEEP_TIME = 3000

    @Rule
    public EmbeddedActiveMQResource server = new EmbeddedActiveMQResource();

    @Autowired
    private JmsService jmsService;

    @Autowired
    private AuditMessageRepository repository

    @Autowired
    private AuditMessageHistoryRepository historyRepository

    @Value("\${ccncsi.audit.topic.toEurope}")
    private String europeDestination

    @Value("\${ccncsi.audit.topic.commands}")
    private String commandsDestination

    private ObjectMapper jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper()

    //def setup() {
      //  server.start()
      //  server.setDefaultReceiveTimeout(SLEEP_TIME)
    //}

    @Retry(delay = 10000)
    def 'Send a valid message to Europe'() {
        when:
        def msg = send(europeDestination,"tests/message1.json")
        then: "Verify if message is inserted in table AUDIT_MESSAGE"
        sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
        List<AuditMessage> messages = repository.findAll().collect()
        messages.size() == 1
        AuditMessage auditMessage = messages.get(0)
        auditMessage.id != null
        auditMessage.messageId == msg.headers.get(Headers.MESSAGE_ID)
        auditMessage.reference == null
        auditMessage.content != null
        auditMessage.content.contentType == "text/plain"
        new String(Base64.decoder.decode(auditMessage.content.content)) == "Here is the body of message1"
        auditMessage.contentStored
        auditMessage.messageTimestamp != null
        auditMessage.creationDate != null
        check(auditMessage, msg, Headers.MESSAGE_ID, Headers.APPLICATION, Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, Headers.COUNTRY_CODE, Headers.QUEUE_BASE_NAME, Headers.MESSAGE_TYPE)
        and: "Check method findByMessageIdOrderByCreation"
        List<AuditMessage> messagesByMessageId = repository.findByMessageIdOrderByCreationDate(auditMessage.getMessageId())
        messagesByMessageId.size() == 1
        messagesByMessageId.get(0).id == auditMessage.id
        and: "Check if a status event is sent"
        sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
        List<AuditMessageHistory> histories = historyRepository.findAll().collect()
        histories.size() == 1
    }

    @Retry(delay = 10000)
    def 'Send a reply message from Europe - with correlationId'() {
        when:
        def msg = send(europeDestination,"tests/message2.json")
        sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
        then: "Verify if message is inserted in table AUDIT_MESSAGE"
        List<AuditMessage> messagesByMessageId = repository.findByMessageIdOrderByCreationDate(msg.headers.get(Headers.MESSAGE_ID))
        messagesByMessageId.size() == 1
        messagesByMessageId.get(0).reference != null
    }

    @Retry(delay = 10000)
    def 'Send message with body null'() {
        when:
        def msg = send(europeDestination,"tests/message5.json")
        sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
        then: "Verify if message is inserted in table AUDIT_MESSAGE and contentStored is false"
        List<AuditMessage> messagesByMessageId = repository.findByMessageIdOrderByCreationDate(msg.headers.get(Headers.MESSAGE_ID))
        messagesByMessageId.size() == 1
        !messagesByMessageId.get(0).contentStored
    }

    @Retry(delay = 10000)
    def 'Bad message3.json -> No inserts'() {
        when:
        def msg = send(europeDestination,"tests/message3.json")
        sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
        then: "Verify if message is not inserted in table AUDIT_MESSAGE"
        List<AuditMessage> messagesByMessageId = repository.findByMessageIdOrderByCreationDate(msg.headers.get(Headers.MESSAGE_ID))
        messagesByMessageId.size() == 0
        List<AuditMessageHistory> messageHistories = repository.findByMessageIdOrderByCreationDate(msg.headers.get(Headers.MESSAGE_ID))
        messageHistories.size() == 0
    }

    //def cleanup() {
      //  server.stop()
      //  sleep(SLEEP_TIME)
    //}

    def get(String path) {
        URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(path)
        return jsonMapper.readValue(url, AuditTestMessage.class)
    }

    def send(String destination, String path) {
        log.error("sending message from file: {} to {}", path.toString(), destination)
        AuditTestMessage msg = get(path)
        jmsService.send(destination, msg.getHeaders(), msg.getBody())
        return msg
    }

    def check(AuditMessage msg1, AuditTestMessage msg2, String... keys) {
        for (String key : keys) {
            if (msg2.getHeaders().get(key) != msg1.getHeaders().get(key)) {
                log.error("Header ["+key+"] : "+ msg1.getHeaders().get(key) + " !=  " + msg2.getHeaders().get(key))
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

**JMSConfig.java**
Below you can see an attempt at setting `subdomain` to `true` on the JMSFactory as I'm sending the  messages to a topic. This did not change any behavior.

```java
package be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.audit.config;

import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.common.service.JmsService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.EnableJms;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DynamicDestinationResolver;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;
import org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageBuilder;

import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Session;
import java.util.Map;

@Configuration
@EnableJms
public class JMSConfig {

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message converter
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        //factory.setPubSubDomain(true);
        // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    JmsService jmsService(@Autowired JmsMessagingTemplate jmsMessagingTemplate) {
        return new JmsService() {
            @Override
            public void send(String destination, Object payload) {
                jmsMessagingTemplate.send(destination, MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload).build());
            }

            @Override
            public void send(String destination, Map<String, Object> headers, Object payload) {
                if (headers == null) send(destination, payload);
                else jmsMessagingTemplate.send(destination, MessageBuilder.withPayload(payload).copyHeaders(headers).build());
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**MessageListener.java**

```java
package be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.audit.listener;

import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.audit.domain.AuditMessage;
import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.audit.service.AuditMessageHistoryService;
import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.audit.service.AuditMessageMapper;
import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.audit.service.AuditMessageService;
import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.common.domain.DestinationType;
import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.common.domain.command.Command;
import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.common.domain.event.StatusEvent;
import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.common.domain.event.StatusType;
import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.common.service.JsonService;
import be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.common.service.StatusEventService;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.jms.annotation.JmsListener;
import org.springframework.jms.core.JmsMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.jms.support.JmsHeaders;
import org.springframework.messaging.Message;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.io.IOException;

@Component
@Slf4j
public class MessageListener {

    private final AuditMessageService service;
    private final AuditMessageMapper mapper;
    private final StatusEventService statusEventService;
    private final JsonService jsonService;
    private final AuditMessageHistoryService historyService;
    private final JmsMessagingTemplate jmsMessagingTemplate;

    @Value("${ccncsi.audit.queue.fromEuropeError:Consumer.ccncsiaudit.VirtualTopic.ccncsi.fromEurope.rme}")
    private String fromEuropeError;

    @Value("${ccncsi.audit.queue.toEuropeError:Consumer.ccncsiaudit.VirtualTopic.ccncsi.toEurope.rme}")
    private String toEuropeError;

    @Autowired
    public MessageListener(AuditMessageService service, AuditMessageMapper mapper, StatusEventService statusEventService,
                           be.fgov.minfin.esbsoa.ems.ccncsi.common.service.JsonService jsonService, AuditMessageHistoryService historyService,
                           JmsMessagingTemplate jmsMessagingTemplate) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.service = service;
        this.statusEventService = statusEventService;
        this.jsonService = jsonService;
        this.historyService = historyService;
        this.jmsMessagingTemplate = jmsMessagingTemplate;
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "${ccncsi.audit.queue.toEurope:Consumer.ccncsiaudit.VirtualTopic.ccncsi.toEurope}", concurrency = "${ccncsi.audit.queue.concurrency:1-10}")
    @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
    public void onMessageToEurope(Message<?> message) {
        save(message, DestinationType.TO_EUROPE);
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "${ccncsi.audit.queue.fromEurope:Consumer.ccncsiaudit.VirtualTopic.ccncsi.fromEurope}", concurrency = "${ccncsi.audit.queue.concurrency:1-10}")
    @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
    public void onMessageFromEurope(Message<?> message) {
        save(message, DestinationType.FROM_EUROPE);
    }

    private void save(Message<?> message, DestinationType destination) {
        AuditMessage auditMessage = service.save(mapper.map(message, destination));
        statusEventService.notify(message.getHeaders(), auditMessage.getId(), StatusType.AUDIT_STORE_SUCCESS);
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "${ccncsi.audit.queue.events:Consumer.ccncsiaudit.VirtualTopic.ccncsi.events}", concurrency = "${ccncsi.audit.queue.concurrency:1-10}")
    @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
    public void onEventMessage(Message<?> event) throws IOException {
        StatusEvent statusEvent = jsonService.fromString((String) event.getPayload(), StatusEvent.class);
        historyService.save(statusEvent);
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "${ccncsi.audit.queue.commands:Consumer.ccncsiaudit.VirtualTopic.ccncsi.commands}", concurrency = "${ccncsi.audit.queue.concurrency:1-10}")
    @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
    public void onCommandMessage(Message<?> command) throws Exception {
        JsonNode jsonCommand = jsonService.fromString((String) command.getPayload());
        service.execute((Command) jsonService.fromJSonNode(jsonCommand, Class.forName(jsonCommand.get("name").textValue())));
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "DLQ.${ccncsi.audit.queue.toEurope:Consumer.ccncsiaudit.VirtualTopic.ccncsi.toEurope}")
    @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
    public void onErrorToEurope(Message<?> message) {
        statusEventService.notify(message.getHeaders(), message.getHeaders().get(JmsHeaders.MESSAGE_ID), StatusType.AUDIT_STORE_FAILED);
        jmsMessagingTemplate.send(toEuropeError, message);
    }

    @JmsListener(destination = "DLQ.${ccncsi.audit.queue.fromEurope:Consumer.ccncsiaudit.VirtualTopic.ccncsi.fromEurope}")
    @Transactional(value = Transactional.TxType.REQUIRED)
    public void onErrorFromEurope(Message<?> message) {
        statusEventService.notify(message.getHeaders(), message.getHeaders().get(JmsHeaders.MESSAGE_ID), StatusType.AUDIT_STORE_FAILED);
        jmsMessagingTemplate.send(fromEuropeError, message);
    }

}
```

Below you can see that I modified the addresses to the artemis format. The specification sends messages to `VirtualTopic.ccncsi.toEurope` (topic) and are received on the consumer queues of this address.

**application.yml** (relevant section)

```yaml
ccncsi:
  common:
    statusEventDestination: VirtualTopic.ccncsi.events
  audit:
    #Maximum size of content (in Kilobytes)
    max-size-content-storage: 5000
    topic:
      toEurope: VirtualTopic.ccncsi.toEurope
      fromEurope: VirtualTopic.ccncsi.fromEurope
      commands: VirtualTopic.ccncsi.commands
    queue:
      toEurope: VirtualTopic.ccncsi.toEurope::Consumer.ccncsiaudit.VirtualTopic.ccncsi.toEurope
      fromEurope: VirtualTopic.ccncsi.fromEurope::Consumer.ccncsiaudit.VirtualTopic.ccncsi.fromEurope
      events: VirtualTopic.ccncsi.events::Consumer.ccncsiaudit.VirtualTopic.ccncsi.events
      commands: VirtualTopic.ccncsi.commands::Consumer.ccncsiaudit.VirtualTopic.ccncsi.commands
      concurrency: 1-30
```

**application-junit.yml**

```yaml
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;NON_KEYWORDS=KEY,VALUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    username: sa
    password: password
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver

  jms:
    pub-sub-domain: true
    template:
      default-destination: VirtualTopic.ccncsi.toEurope

#  artemis:
#    embedded:
#      enabled: true
#      persistent: true
#    mode: embedded
#    broker-url: vm://0?virtualTopicConsumerWildcards=Consumer.*.%3E%3B2
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Since Spock 2.x `@Rule` requires the `spock-junit4` module, it didn't see it listed in your dependencies.

Comment: The use of virtual topics might be a problem. In any case, it's a layer of complexity that isn't really necessary with ActiveMQ Artemis. ActiveMQ "Classic" implemented virtual topics so you could use JMS topic semantics when sending messages and JMS queue semantics when consuming messages. This isn't really necessary anymore with JMS 2 which allows for shared topic subscriptions which basically provides all the same benefits as virtual topics but in a standard way that's portable across JMS brokers. Is there a specific reason why you're using virtual topics? I would encourage you to drop them.

Comment: @LeonardBrünings thank you for your comment. I removed the junit dependency and changed it to spock-junit4. However, this did not change the behavior of the specification.

Comment: @JustinBertram thank you for your comment. I -think- shared subscriptions  is how my brokers are configured. If I look  at my broker configuration for `VirtualTopic.ccncsi.toEurope`, it's the following: ```xml<address name="VirtualTopic.ccncsi.toEurope">
                <multicast>
                                    <queue name="Consumer.dispatcher.VirtualTopic.ccncsi.toEurope"/>
                        <queue name="Consumer.ccncsiaudit.VirtualTopic.ccncsi.toEurope"/>
                                </multicast>
            </address>``` .

Comment: (continued) however, I am not sure I have adapted the @JmsListeners and the jmsTemplate correctly to use them like I should.